# How to find which part of a binary requires a certain version of a certain dependency?

Tags: linux, build, linker, glibc, buck

I am compiling some inherited code onto a linux platform. When I try to run it, I get a library versioning error:

```
[aardvark@aardvark-burrow /data/users/aardvark/project-source]  /data/users/aardvark/project-source/buck-out/gen/arvr/projects/viper/applications/replay/fcv_replay
/data/users/aardvark/project-source/buck-out/gen/arvr/projects/viper/applications/replay/fcv_replay: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /data/users/aardvark/project-source/buck-out/gen/arvr/projects/viper/applications/replay/fcv_replay)
```

First off, who cares that I have GLIBC_2.28, not 2.29, and why do they care? Is it a compile flag passed to build the final executable (fcv_replay), or one of its many dependencies? How do I find out? I basically want to know what to look for inside a large, complex build system that I didn't create.

Here are the results of another query:

```
[aardvark@ /data/users/aardvark/project-source] ldd /data/users/aardvark/project-source/buck-out/gen/arvr/projects/viper/applications/replay/fcv_replay
/data/users/aardvark/project-source/buck-out/gen/arvr/projects/viper/applications/replay/fcv_replay: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /data/users/aardvark/project-source/buck-out/gen/arvr/projects/viper/applications/replay/fcv_replay)
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe84592000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe4daefd000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe4dab7b000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe4da977000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe4da5b2000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe4db11d000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fe4da39a000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You app, `fcv_replay`, has been compiled on a newer Linux distro (or a new toolchain) and is using some new functions from `libm` library which are missing in your current distro.

You can see which part of the executable is causing the problem by inspecting the disassembly:

```
$ objdump -dr /bin/nautilus | grep -C5 GLIBC_2.29 | head
000000000004a430 <pow@plt>:
   4a430:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
   4a434:   f2 ff 25 45 1e 16 00    bnd jmpq *0x161e45(%rip)        # 1ac280 <pow@GLIBC_2.29>
   4a43b:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
...
```

The best solution would be to rebuild `fcv_replay` on the oldest possible distro to avoid dependency on new versions of libc.

Comment: Sounds good, except that I am compiling and running on the same VM. FWIW, here is the 'uname -a' spew, it's a newish CentOS VM.

        

`Linux aardvark-burrow.zoo.com 5.6.13-0_fbk19_hardened_6064_gabfd136bb69a #1 SMP Fri Oct 22 10:57:22 PDT 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: @AdventurousAardvark that's interesting, can you link with `-Wl,--verbose` and check which `libm.so.6` is used during linking? I assume it's _not_ `/lib64/libm.so.6`.

Comment: Right you is: grepping the log turned up:

`
11981:ld.lld: ./arvr/third-party/toolchains/platform009/build/glibc/lib/libm.so.6
`

It makes sense that some of the libraries that my binary depends upon would link out of stuff in there. 

But there is another mystery - probing that libm.so.6, seems to point back to the right libc.so.6 file: 

`
[aardvark@aardvark.burrow.zoo ~/fbsource] ldd ./arvr/third-party/toolchains/platform009/build/glibc/lib/libm.so.6
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f15587b9000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1558b7e000)
`

Comment: Running:  
`objdump -dr ./arvr/third-party/toolchains/platform009/build/glibc/lib/libm.so.6 | grep  GLIBC_2\.2[0-9]+`.   
  
Earns (duplicate lines trimmed):  
 
`10fba:       72 04                   jb     10fc0 <lgammal@@GLIBC_2.23+0x30>. 
41ac8:       73 06                   jae    41ad0 <log@@GLIBC_2.29+0x10>. `. 

Not sure what is happening, but it looks like a math library (log, pow, etc.) was linked against 2.29, and another was linked against 2.23?  
Como esta?

Comment: "probing that libm.so.6, seems to point back to the right libc.so.6 file" - in your default environment yes but during linking most likely another `libc.so.6` (from `arvr/third-party/toolchains`) was picked up due to `-L` compiler flags.

Comment: @AdventurousAardvark "it looks like a math library was linked against 2.29, and another was linked against 2.23" - right, functions that have not been changed since libc 2.23 will still have old version. Only modified functions will be of version 2.29.